# How make simple aggregation pipeline faster?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collections containing documents of the following structure:

```
{
   my_array: [
      {
          x: 1,
          y: 2,
          z: 3
      },
      ... // from 10 to 100 items here
   ],
   some_field: some_value,
   ... // few additional fields here
}
```

I'd like to make some kind of benchmark that will scan all the arrays in all my documents, because it will be the common way to such collections in the production. For instance, I wrote an aggregation pipeline that finds minimum `x` in all the documents:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {$project: {max_x: {$max: "$my_array.x"}, _id: false}},
        {$group: {_id: null, max_x: {$max: "$max_x"}}}
    ]
)'
```

Unfortunately the performance of this query is very slow, Mongo uses 100% CPU while read speed is ~10 MB/s with compressed table and ~40 MB/s with uncompressed table. I know that my storage can work faster, for example PostgreSQL make `SELECT MIN(x) FROM table` much faster and reads ~150 MB/s. For Mongo total execution time for both compressed and uncompressed tables are almost the same, so it shouldn't be issue with compression. I have also tried aggregate pipeline that uses `$unwind` instead of `$max` on the `$project` stage but it was even slower.

Please, can you help me to understand what is wrong with my aggregation pipeline of document structure.

I have performed queries on official Docker image with Mongo 4.2, with two hardware configurations (the first is twice faster probably due to more performant CPU): 1) Xeon X5675, 8GB RAM, HDD RAID storage, 2) ARMv8 64-bit Cortex A72, 1GB RAM, m.2 SSD. Uncompressed collection size is much larger than RAM, in the production it will be not possible to have as much RAM as collection size (about 1 TB per host).

Comment: I guess you cant compare, RDBMS with Mongodb, in terms of performance

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/

Can you try adding index to mongodb collection on the fields that you are querying to support faster read and check the performance

Comment: I don't try to compare with PostreSQL, I just try to understand why Mongo uses so much CPU in my case. For some queries I have to scan the full collection, so it is important to make it as fast as storage IO. I have indexes that work fine for another queries.